# Add custom ID to LayerGroup selector checkbox in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, jquery, leaflet, gis

I have Leaflet version 1.0.0
I am trying to add an ID to the layer group selector.
How can I add a custom ID or any other attributes to selector checkbox?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
var parkingExisting = new L.LayerGroup();

// Existing Parking
var parkingExistingStyle = {
    color: "#418532",
    fillColor: "#418532",
    fillOpacity: 0.4,
    weight: 1
};

function parkingExistingJSONLoaded(){
    L.geoJSON(parkingExistingDataSet, {
        style: parkingExistingStyle,
    }).addTo(parkingExisting);
}
```

Comment: I don't 100% get your question. IDs should be placed by the HTML-generator (a file or PHP or whatever) so you can identify an element later. If you add IDs dynamically in the client(browser), then you would need to know for 100% which ID is available for usage and which are not. So... just place them there on HTML-creation or maybe tell us more about your use-case, so we can maybe hint you to a better solution :)

Comment: @spyro Leaflet this is a JavaScript library and there is no HTML, all HTML code generating with JavaScript. Your suggestion not exactly about Leaflet.js

Comment: Are you using any frameworks or leaflet plugins to display those checkboxes?

Comment: @IvanSanchez I am using the library from this Leaflet website: https://leafletjs.com/download.html

Comment: Seems that you're using https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl . This is an important piece of information that should be in your original question.

Comment: The code for Leaflet.StyledLayerControl should [already be adding a unique ID to each checkbox](https://github.com/davicustodio/Leaflet.StyledLayerControl/blob/master/src/styledLayerControl.js#L368). Please edit your question to reflect your Leaflet version,your version of Leaflet.StyledLayerControl, and the bits of code where you add such a control to your map instance.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I have Leaflet 1.0.0 but not sure about Leaflet.StyledLayerControl version. I am not sure if I can update to the current Leaflet version as we have a lot of custom changes to the Leaflet.StyledLayerControl.

Comment: @IvanSanchez you right I have outdated Leaflet.StyledLayerControl version, without input.id, I am not really yet sure how can I update the version without losing custom code changes. Or at least adding id generating function.

Comment: @bohdanbaida i didn't say you should look into an HTML-file. I said: 'IDs should be placed by the HTML-generator (a file or PHP or whatever)'. So If your HTML-Code is generated by Leaflet, then Leaflet must provide IDs for those elements. If it isn't in the default settings, you have to edit the settings. If it uses html-templates or patterns, then you need to edit those. WHY the ID is not presented in your code has to be figured out by you (with our help). But since we don't have 100% of your code for the webpage, you either have to provide it or debug stuff yourself and report back to us.

Comment: @spyro question was not about HTML or so, it was about Leaflet.js library and leaflet function that creates ID for the checkbox. But anyways thank for your help, I really appreciate it. IvanSanchez already pointed me to the correct version of Leaflet.StyledLayerControl that I needed.